# Recording multiple midi inputs to separate tracks on garageband

Tags: audio, microphone, garageband, recording, midi

Is there a way to record multiple midi inputs to separate tracks simultaneously using garageband?

I'm holding an interview tomorrow and want a microphone for the subject and myself. I need to separately edit the tracks.

Comment: Midi inputs for a microphone?

Comment: 2 USB microphones recording to separate tracks.

Comment: Nothing to do with MIDI then ;) MIDI stands for Musical Instrument Digital Interface, which doesn't encompass audio at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found that the 'Show Record Enable' function had been disabled.

To enable it, right click on a track, Track Header Components > Show Record Enable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UrRzbLvsqc#t=36

You can then click the record button for each track you want to record simultaneously.